# ionic cap run ios on m1

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, apple-m1

Im trying to run `ionic cap run ios` on a m1 mac and I keep getting a long error (~900,000 char long) part of the last chunk of the error says

`CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'Capacitor' from project 'Pods')`

which leads me to think its an issue with m1 using arm.

Ive tried running terminal in rosetta and normally and I have installed ffi (both suggested by similar but not the same question)

does anyone know whats going on here and how to fix it?

a bit more of the error log for more context

`CompileC /Users ... long file path ... /CordovaPluginFileTransfer/CDVFileTransfer.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'CordovaPlugins' from project 'Pods') [capacitor]         (2 failures)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it with [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/issues/258) issue.

I uninstalled the current plugin and then I did the steps described [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer) but used the recommended [plugin](https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) from the issue.

```
$ npm install https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-file-transfer
$ npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/file-transfer 
$ ionic cap sync
```

Hope this would help.